# Merging Two Identical Feature Classes in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, merge, error-000258

I used the arcGIS tool feature class to feature class to successfull merge two identical feature classes [one with partial data and the other resting on a database connection]. However when I attempt to do this with arcPY I get a ERROR 000258: layer already exists, failed to execute .

The call looks like this

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("roads", C:\fullPathTo.sde, "roads")
```

Other enviromental varibles have been set accordingly, but I am looking for what the GUI tool does in this situation, an automatic merge, taking the left [local] data and meging it into the .sde.

Answer (score 1):

Feature class to feature class doesn't merge, it overwrites if allowed, or will give an error if the feature class already exists. If able to overwrite you will **lose** any data in the feature class that is overwritten - it will not be in the end result.

You need to use either:

1. The [Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) tool to merge two feature classes together into a new feature class with a new name
2. The [Append](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) tool to merge one into another existing feature class (which is what I think you want to do)

Comment: What if we want to overwrite using feature class? Merge creates duplicate fields when I attempt and Append creates a shp file as opposed to feature layers